# how can i put an answer for a shuffled question in python

Tags: python

I am making a quiz in python with 3 questions. One question is randomly selected and there has to be an answer for the question, but i don't know how to put an answer to a question which has random.choice or anything to do with shuffling questions.

So I want one of the 3 questions to be randomly picked and there to be an answer for the randomly picked question. If they get the answer wrong, repeat the question, if they get it right, the next question appears.

this is the code I have come up with. I know it is quiet basic but I am fairly new to python. I have searched for answer but couldn't find any. Please help me

python
import random

#The questions

question = ["How many days are there in a year?", "How many days are in a century?", "How many hours are in a day"]

print(random.choice(question))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for, but try this out; you can have a dictionary of question & answers:

```
import random
QnA= {
"How many days are there in a year?":"365", 
"How many days are in a century?":"36500", 
"How many hours are in a day":"24"
}   
#The questions
question = list(QnA.keys())
#input answer here 
while True:
    if not question:
        break
    ques = random.choice(question)
    print(ques)
    while True:
        answer = input('Answer : ')
        if answer == QnA[ques]:
            print("Correct Answer")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong Answer")
    question.remove(ques)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will ask each question in random order

```
# Uses method from
# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shuffle-two-lists-with-same-order/
# to generate random list of questions and answers in same order

import random

questions = ["How many days are there in a year?", "How many days are in a century?", "How many hours are in a day"]
answers = [365, 
           365*100,   # ignoring leap years
           24]

qa_pairs = list(zip(questions, answers))   # list of question/answer pairs
random.shuffle(qa_pairs)                   # list of question/answer pairs in random order

question, answer = qa_pairs.pop()          # Get question & answer from list (pop returns last pair, but we don't care about order)
while True:
    # Ask last question in list
    response = int(input(question))         # User answer

    if response == answer:
        # Next  question and answer
        if qa_pairs:
            question, answer = qa_pairs.pop()
        else:
            break   # Out of questions
    else:
        print('Incorrect, try again')
```